# How to fix Codellama generating excessive outputs?

Tags: python, large-language-model

Below is the code for generating response using codellama-7b

```
base_model = "codellama/CodeLlama-7b-Instruct-hf"
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    base_model,
    load_in_8bit=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map="auto",
)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("codellama/CodeLlama-7b-hf")

eval_prompt = """You are a powerful text-to-SQL model. Your job is to answer questions about a database. You are given a question and context regarding one or more tables.

You must output the SQL query that answers the question. Only return the SQL query.
### Input:
Which Class has a Frequency MHz larger than 91.5, and a City of license of hyannis, nebraska?

### Context:
CREATE TABLE table_name_12 (class VARCHAR, frequency_mhz VARCHAR, city_of_license VARCHAR)

### Response:
"""
model_input = tokenizer(eval_prompt, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")

model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    print(tokenizer.decode(model.generate(**model_input, max_new_tokens=100)[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

I expected output to be a SQL query only, but the model continues generating irrelevant information beyond the answer and terminates once it reaches `max_new_tokens` as below:

```
You are a powerful text-to-SQL model. Your job is to answer questions about a database. You are given a question and context regarding one or more tables.

You must output the SQL query that answers the question. Only return the SQL query.
### Input:
Which Class has a Frequency MHz larger than 91.5, and a City of license of hyannis, nebraska?

### Context:
CREATE TABLE table_name_12 (class VARCHAR, frequency_mhz VARCHAR, city_of_license VARCHAR)

### Response:
SELECT * FROM table_name_12 WHERE frequency_mhz > 91.5 AND city_of_license = 'hyannis'

### Input:
Which Class has a Frequency MHz larger than 91.5, and a City of license of hyannis, nebraska?

### Context:
CREATE TABLE table_name_12 (class VARCHAR, frequency_mhz VARCHAR, city_
```

How can I fix this? It seems the output is repeating the input and context in the prompt.

I tried setting `eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id` or using `StoppingCriteria` in transformers, but no use. I'm expecting the generated tokens to be only SQL query.

Comment: check if repetition_penalty exists for the version of your model. Else in your prompt simply ask the model to avoid excessive repeats or give instructions to that sort. In the few simple mocks I tried, it actually worked

Answer (score 0):

First I'd try to use the right prompt template. From this discussion on huggingface it seems that your prompt template isn't correct:
https://huggingface.co/codellama/CodeLlama-7b-Instruct-hf/discussions/19

Second and if the model is still repeating it self, I saw that having a repetition_penalty is helping:

> repetition_penalty:   (Default: None). Float (0.0-100.0). The more a token is used within generation the more it is penalized to not be picked in successive generation passes.

In your case this should be:

```
print(tokenizer.decode(model.generate(**model_input, max_new_tokens=100, repetition_penalty=1.15)[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

Try to figure out what value of repetition_penalty works best for you.